# Will Java execute two TRUE Switch cases?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Here is my code:

```
int x = 10;
switch(x) {
    case 10:
        System.out.println("10");
        break;
    case 5+5:
        System.out.println("5+5");
        break;
}
```

Here in this case, both cases are true, what will be executed? first case, or both?

Comment: What does it do, and what do you expect?

Comment: This code will fail with compilation error "Duplicate label 10". What to explain?

Comment: apart from the answers given your switch clause should also contain a default: statement. This will not give an error but it's very much recommended

Comment: Did someone stopped you from writing the code and using the debugger (if it succeeds compilation) ? Eclipse is an open source so as java :)

Answer (score 9):

It's invalid: 5+5 resolves to 10, and you cannot have two `case` clauses with the same constant.

Answer (score 2):

As `5+5` is compiled as `10`, your code has duplicate conditions, which is illegal in java switch statements.

From the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) :

> No two of the case constant expressions associated with a switch
>   statement may have the same value.

So nobody can "explain the execution" : there is no execution.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a "duplicate case" error.

According to your comment, this is the issue you observed.

The explaination is that `5+5` is evaluated to `10` at compile time by the compiler, which means that you have two case branches with the same value. This is not allowed (which one should the code take?)

Answer (score 1):

Each case statement in a switch block must be unique. `case 10` and `case 5 + 5` are the same thing, and as such your code will not compile.